# C++ Pointers In A Game

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am in what seems to be a never ending quest to understand pointers. I finally have a working code using pointers to create a quick character and enemy, then mock an overly simple battle. It works 100% as it seems, but I'm not 100% sure it's correct or what I did to make it right. I have read 13 chapters so far in my C++ book (2 being over pointers specifically), but I'm still not sure it's clicked. If this looks like a valid use and proper utilization of them, I think I'm getting there, just wanted some clarification if it is. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H

class Unit
{
public:
    Unit(const std::string name, int hp, int power);
    ~Unit();

    void    printHP();
    void    attack(Unit* unit);
    bool    isDead();

private:
    std::string     mName;
    int             mHP;
    int             mPower;

};

Unit::Unit(const std::string name, int hp, int power)
{
    mName   = name;
    mHP     = hp;
    mPower  = power;
}
void Unit::printHP()
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << mName << "'s HP: " << mHP << std::endl;
}
void Unit::attack(Unit* unit)
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << unit->mName << " takes " << this->mPower << " damage! " << std::endl;
    unit->mHP -= this->mPower;
}
bool Unit::isDead()
{
    return this->mHP < 1;
}
Unit::~Unit()
{

}
#endif

int main()
{
    Unit player1("GoodFellow", 20, 5);
    Unit Enemy("ABadMan", 10, 2);

    while (!Enemy.isDead())
    {
        player1.printHP();
        Enemy.printHP();

        player1.attack(&Enemy);
        Enemy.attack(&player1);
    }
}
```

Modified it to this... I think I get the reason for only using a reference, just trying to get the concept of pointers....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H

class Unit
{
public:
    Unit(const std::string name, int hp, int power);
    ~Unit();

    void    printHP();
    void    attack(Unit& unit);
    bool    isDead();

    void    setHP(int hp);

private:
    std::string     mName;
    int             mHP;
    int             mPower;

};

Unit::Unit(const std::string name, int hp, int power)
{
    mName   = name;
    mHP     = hp;
    mPower  = power;
}
void Unit::printHP()
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << mName << "'s HP: " << mHP << std::endl;
}
void Unit::attack(Unit& unit)
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << unit.mName << " takes " << this->mPower << " damage! " << std::endl;
    unit.mHP -= this->mPower;
}
bool Unit::isDead()
{
    return this->mHP < 1;
}
void Unit::setHP(int hp)
{
    this->mHP = hp;
}
Unit::~Unit()
{

}
#endif

int main()
{
    Unit player1("GoodFellow", 20, 5);
    Unit Enemy("ABadMan", 10, 2);

    while (true)
    {
        while (!Enemy.isDead())
        {
            player1.printHP();
            Enemy.printHP();

            player1.attack(Enemy);
            Enemy.attack(player1);
        }

        char playAgain;
        std::cout << "Fight again? (y)/(n)" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> playAgain;

        if (playAgain == 'n')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Enemy.setHP(10);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, you don't need to use pointers at all. So, I would not say you have a "valid use and proper utilization of them".

Comment: Your question is a bit broad... But for passing objects-by-reference in C++ you should not use pointers, but references instead

Comment: If you really want to grok pointers, learn one of the assembly languages. I recommend the M68000 since it has a programmer-friendly design.

Comment: I think pointers are fine in this case. It suggests he's going to modify the argument which may not be obvious from a nonconst reference.

Comment: @user2345215 A non-const reference definitely suggests it's going to be modified. A raw pointer, on the other hand, suggests that `nullptr` is a valid value to pass.

Comment: @sftrabbit But a pointer suggests that everywhere you call it, not just from the declaration which can be anywhere. I guess it's a matter of style.

Comment: Every programmer in a C-based language is on a never-ending quest to understand pointers.  So you're in good company.

Comment: @user2345215 I suppose. I tend to think about the code as a whole, not just as what the programmer can see immediately. My thought is that a responsible programmer either looks at the function declaration or has an IDE to do it for her.

Comment: The question should be on CodeReview.

Comment: While I don't see anything *illegal* or Undefined about how you're using pointers here, I certainly would never do it this way.  First off, I would not use pointers unless I had no other choice, and you have other choices here.  Second, if I were to use pointers, I wouldn't do it the way you're doing it.  So, valid perhaps, but not a proper use case.  I think you would be better served by asking a question about what you don't get about pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's a reasonable use of pointers. I was actually glad to see that you used them very little. I was half expecting to see `Unit* player1 = new Unit ...` and such all over the place. But no, you used automatic storage duration all over (rather than dynamic), which was very appropriate.

So the main reason for passing `Unit*`s to the `attack` functions is to that inside the function you can modify the `Unit` that you're attacking and have the effect seen outside. If you were to pass the `Unit`s directly, they would be copied into the function and then the `unit->mHP -= this->mPower;` would only affect the copy.

However, there is a more appropriate tool at your disposal here. You can use *references*. A reference also allows you to pass an object without copying it, so that modifications inside the function can be seen outside. Your attack function signature would change to:

```
void Unit::attack(Unit& unit)
```

The type `Unit&` is a "reference to `Unit`". Don't confuse the use of `&` with taking the address of an object - it means something completely different here. You would then call it like so:

```
player1.attack(Enemy);
```

The point is you should try to avoid pointers as much as possible. Since you can use references here, which are safer (you do not need to check for `null`), you should use them.

It's fine to learn about how pointers to work, but in doing so, you should learn how to use other more appropriate tools for the job.

Comment: I think I have a firm understanding of references already (I am a c# developer), just pointers lost me somewhere along the way.

Comment: @Volearix Well here, references are the better tool to use. A raw pointer to non-const object represents non-owning writeable access to an object or no object (null). A reference represents non-owning writeable access to an object. It is more specific.

Comment: @Volearix Pointers are semantically identical to references, EXCEPT that i) they may have a NULL value, ii) under-the-hood, a pointer's value behaves like an integer, holding the data's memory address (or 0/NULL), iii) because of ii, a pointer may be reassigned to point at a different data address (unlike a reference, which cannot). I agree with sftrabbit -- prefer references wherever possible. It makes reasoning about code easier because a reference should never be null.